# why won't this modulo program give a answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

This simple modulo inverse program I wrote either ends with no answer or doesn't end what's the flaw. I run with inputs 11 for 'y' and 26 for 'm'  which then should make x=19 but this is never the result unless I run basic if a==1 then x is reciprocal which doesn't work if you don't know what x needs to be.

```
x=1
y=int(input('determinant:'))
m=int(input('modulo:'))
a=y*x%m
while a != 1:
     print(x)
     x = x+1
     if a == 1:
       print('this is the reciprocal: ' + str(x))
       break
print('this is the reciprocal: ' + str(x))
```

Comment: Could you give us the output a full run of the program?

Comment: because 26 modulo 11 is 4 and not equal to 1 according to your code so it will continue printing x from 1 to infinity because modulo is always 4 and your if statement is `if modulo equals 1`. What I mean is : `y*x%m` is not the inverse of a modulo function.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what the calculation is (or what a modulo inverse is). But I am guessing it has something to do with the fact that the calculation of a is done only once (before the while loop). You update x in the loop, but the calculation is done only with the original x of 1.